# Nginx as a proxy doesn't allow to access backend (Apache) content which is password protected

Tags: apache-2.2, nginx, proxy, http-basic-authentication

I have apache as a backend and nginx as a frontend. Some content is password-protected by Apache (HTTP Auth).

When I access it directly - everything works fine, bur when I try it through nginx - seems like nginx doesn't forward or cache the responses from Apache.
So inside nginx log I see:

```
89.21.92.0 - - [17/May/2012:22:13:42 +0200]  GET / HTTP/1.1 | upstream_address x.x.x.x:80 | upstream_status 401 | upstream_response_time 0.026 | msec 1337285622.757 | request_time 0.026
89.21.92.0 - zentavr [17/May/2012:22:13:44 +0200]  GET / HTTP/1.1 | upstream_address - | upstream_status - | upstream_response_time - | msec 1337285624.151 | request_time 0.000
```

On Apache's side:

```
y.y.y.y - - [17/May/2012:22:13:42 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 401 652 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:12.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/12.0" "89.21.92.0"
```

What could be the issue?

Comment: Do you want the client to provide the credentials and have nginx pass them through to Apache, or do you want nginx to provide the credentials to Apache and not require authentication from the client?

Comment: What error code does the client get?  What's the nginx config look like?

Comment: mgorven - the credentials file is on Apache website. So the chain is: Client (enters password) - nginx - Apache with htpasswd database

Comment: Try adding to nginx server configuration:      proxy_set_header Authorization $http_authorization;